# Cell Imageview change on longpress

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

Trying to follow this one:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath//tableview delegate
{
    //here is the code to create and customize a cell
    //adding gesture recognizer
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(your_function)];
    recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0; //seconds
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
    [lpgr release];
    return  cell;
}

-(void)your_function
{
    NSlog(@"detecting long press");
}
```

Here's my question:

How can I make a cell imageview to change after longpress gesture?

I suppose I need to insert a "cell changing" code in `-(void)your_function {}`.

Question Update

Using this for real:

With this one when I click on a cell (longpress) the 4 customized items appear but when I select one of them the app crashes. 
(if you remove :(Cell*)cell  and cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedRED.png"]]; it works...I mean the alertView appears but of course the image don't change).

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        Cell *cell = (Cell *)recognizer.view;
        [cell becomeFirstResponder];

        UIMenuItem *highDep = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"High Dependency" action:@selector(hiDep:)];
        UIMenuItem *lowDep = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Low Dependency" action:@selector(lowDep:)];
        UIMenuItem *booked = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Booked"     action:@selector(booked:)];
        UIMenuItem *free = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Free" action:@selector(free:)];

            UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:booked, highDep, lowDep, free, nil]];
        [menu setTargetRect:cell.frame inView:cell.superview];
        [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];



   }
```

}

the voids are:

```
 - (void)hiDep:(Cell*)cell
 {
    NSLog(@"Bed is HiDep");

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedRED.png"]];




     UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This Bed is High Dependency"
                                                    message:@""
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"   otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];



    [testAlert show];
    [testAlert release];


  }

- (void)lowDep:(Cell*)cell
 {...}

 - (void)free:(Cell*)cell
 {...}

 - (void)booked:(Cell*)cell
 {...}
```

and the cell building method is:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    Cell *cvc = (Cell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int i = indexPath.row%[labelArray count];
    number = i;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];



    [cvc addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


    cvc.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icubed.png"]];
    cvc.label.text =  [labelArray objectAtIndex:number];

       return cvc;


}
```

Answer (score -1):

change the method to:

```
-(void)your_function:(UITableViewCell*)cell
{
    cell.imageView = .....
}
```

The recogniser will send the cell as the sender of the press and will pass it to your method.

**Attention** You will have to set change the recogniser to :

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(your_function:)];
```

Add **:** to the end of the method, since your method gets a parameter.

Comment: Thanx a lot, maybe a little bit more complicated: I'll update the question.